# Respected Citizen rewards

Tags: descent

In Encounter 2 of the Respected Citizen quest of the Shadow of Nerekhall campaign the rewards include:

> If Bertram is present during the quest and not defeated, during the next Shopping step of the Campaign Phase, the heroes reveal one additional Shop Item card per hero.
>
> If Bertram is defeated, the overlord receives “The Scoundrel,” Corrupt Citizen card.

The setup for Encounter 2 includes:

> If the heroes won Encounter 1, they place a villager token in an empty space adjacent to a hero figure. This is Bertram.

The heroes win Encounter 1 “if Bertram is knocked out”. Otherwise the overlord wins by moving him off the map.

**Questions**

- Do the heroes get their Bertram reward if the overlord wins Encounter 1?
- If the overlord wins Encounter 1, can ze not get zir Bertram reward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the Victory section of Encounter 1 it reads:

> If the overlord wins, he immediately receives “The Scoundrel” Corrupt Citizen card.

So the answer to the second question is no. If he won Encounter 1 he already has it.

The answer to the first question: they probably meant encounter rather than quest; otherwise your interpretation is correct and the “If” is redundant.